# Carbon Date formatting in Laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have an array of Carbon Objects being passed to a view like so:

```
return view('booking.choose-days')->with(['weekDays' => $weekDays]);
```

To test that all is ok, I've DD'd the array and see that the arrays of dates are correctly being passed through:

```
array:14 [▼
  0 => Carbon {#252 ▼
    +"date": "2017-04-11 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/London"
  }
  1 => Carbon {#257 ▼
    +"date": "2017-04-12 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/London"
  }
  2 => Carbon {#256 ▼
    +"date": "2017-04-13 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/London"
  }
  3 => Carbon {#255 ▼
    +"date": "2017-04-14 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/London"
  }

...and so forth
```

When looping through the array in Blade using the following (full html left out):

```
@foreach ($weekDays as $key => $weekDay)
    <tr id="{{ $key }}">
      <td>
        {{ $weekDay }}
      </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This produces the expected output of:

```
2017-04-11 00:00:00

2017-04-12 00:00:00

2017-04-13 00:00:00

2017-04-14 00:00:00

2017-04-15 00:00:00

...and so forth
```

However, when instead output:

```
@foreach ($weekDays as $key => $weekDay)
    <tr id="{{ $key }}">
      <td>
        {{ $weekDay->dayOfWeek }} // now accessing a property
      </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I get an output of:

```
1
1
2
2
2
```

Instead of the expected `1,2,3,4,5` for `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday` etc.

So the dates in the array are correct when `var_dumped` as `objects`, but when accessing a property like `dayOfWeek`, it's giving me incorrect properties.

The dates are generated by first reading `two timestamps` from a URL - the `start date` and the `end date`. Both these values are then stored in variables and sent to a function to remove all the weekend dates.

This is the call to the function:

```
$weekDays = getWeekDays(Carbon::createFromTimestamp($startDate), Carbon::createFromTimestamp($endDate));
```

And here’s the function :

```
function getWeekDays(Carbon $startDate, Carbon $endDate)
{
    for($date = $startDate; $startDate->lte($endDate); $startDate->addDay()) {
        if ($date->isWeekDay()) {
            $weekdays[] = clone $date;
        }
    }

    return $weekdays;
}
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But thanks.

Comment: Even more weird, If I pass in array of just 5 consecutive days or less, it works using my original code above. Anything more than 5 days, it goes a bit loopy (like myself after looking at the code for 5 hours!)

Comment: Something is wrong with your dates...i have just tried to recreate the problem...and this can maybe happen if you are somehow converting one variables date and assigning it to another variable. For example if you do this `$b = $a->addDay();` this will actually change the variable $a also and $a and $b will be the same variable! Show us how do you get the dates?

Comment: can you try this and send? I feel like you are overriding this function somewhere  
https://paste.laravel.io/kQ9O7

Comment: Thanks Rodrane. Yes your code does work, but I'm still none the wiser as to why or how the dates are failing! I might try to see what happens when I generate the dates from a string (e.g. '03/03/2017') instead of a timestamp...

Comment: Hold that. No sorry, passing the array you created to the same function still fails when going over 5 consecutive days. So work for Mon-Fri for example, but Mon-Mon outputs wrong days! The function is not working it seems...

Comment: Problem solved. This wil probably annoy you, but I had javascript changing the output without me knowing! So sorry if I wasted your time! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ows post your answer to close your question may be it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this code :

```
 @foreach ($weekDays as $key => $weekDay)
<tr id="{{ $key }}">
  <td>
    {{    \Carbon\Carbon::parse($weekDay)->format('d/m/Y')->dayOfWeek }} // now accessing a property
  </td>
</tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Cheers. I'll have a look at this later!